# Subscript in facet_wrap without label_parsed?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I cannot reduce my problem down to a proper MWE, so I hope I provide enough information to solve my issue. I have a large data frame and I want to use `facet_wrap(~var)`, so on the variable `var`. This variable is a factor containing the following elements

```
  > dat$var
  [1] n = 601  n = 601  n = 601  n = 601  n = 601  n = 601  n = 750  n = 750  n = 750  n = 750  n = 750  n = 750 
 [13] n = 1000 n = 1000 n = 1000 n = 1000 n = 1000 n = 1000 n = 1250 n = 1250 n = 1250 n = 1250 n = 1250 n = 1250
 [25] n = 1500 n = 1500 n = 1500 n = 1500 n = 1500 n = 1500 s010     s010     s010     s010     s010     s010    
 [37] s025     s025     s025     s025     s025     s025     s050     s050     s050     s050     s050     s050    
 [49] s075     s075     s075     s075     s075     s075     s0100    s0100    s0100    s0100    s0100    s0100   
 [61] rho0.1   rho0.1   rho0.1   rho0.1   rho0.1   rho0.1   rho0.3   rho0.3   rho0.3   rho0.3   rho0.3   rho0.3  
 [73] rho0.5   rho0.5   rho0.5   rho0.5   rho0.5   rho0.5   rho0.7   rho0.7   rho0.7   rho0.7   rho0.7   rho0.7  
 [85] rho0.9   rho0.9   rho0.9   rho0.9   rho0.9   rho0.9   SNR = 1  SNR = 1  SNR = 1  SNR = 1  SNR = 1  SNR = 1 
 [97] SNR = 2  SNR = 2  SNR = 2  SNR = 2  SNR = 2  SNR = 2  SNR = 3  SNR = 3  SNR = 3  SNR = 3  SNR = 3  SNR = 3 
[109] SNR = 4  SNR = 4  SNR = 4  SNR = 4  SNR = 4  SNR = 4  SNR = 5  SNR = 5  SNR = 5  SNR = 5  SNR = 5  SNR = 5 
20 Levels: n = 601 n = 750 n = 1000 n = 1250 n = 1500 s010 s025 s050 s075 s0100 rho0.1 rho0.3 rho0.5 ... SNR = 5
```

and levels

```
levels(dat$var)
 [1] "n = 601"  "n = 750"  "n = 1000" "n = 1250" "n = 1500" "s010"     "s025"     "s050"     "s075"     "s0100"   
[11] "rho0.1"   "rho0.3"   "rho0.5"   "rho0.7"   "rho0.9"   "SNR = 1"  "SNR = 2"  "SNR = 3"  "SNR = 4"  "SNR = 5".
```

My current approach to label the headers of each graph was

```
names_head <- c(`n = 601` = "n = 601", 
                `n = 750` = "n = 750",
                `n = 1000` = "n = 1000",
                `n = 1250` = "n = 1250",
                `n = 1500` = "n = 1500",
                `s010` =  "|S| = 10",  `s025` = "|S| = 25",  `s050` = "|S| = 50",
                `s075` = "|S| = 75",  `s0100` = "|S| = 100",
                `rho0.1` = "\u03c1 = 0.1", `rho0.3` = "\u03c1 = 0.3", `rho0.5` = "\u03c1 = 0.5",
                `rho0.7` = "\u03c1 = 0.7", `rho0.9` = "\u03c1 = 0.9", 
                `SNR = 1` = "SNR = 1", `SNR = 2` = "SNR = 2", `SNR = 3` = "SNR = 3",
                `SNR = 4` = "SNR = 4", `SNR = 5` = "SNR = 5")
```

and I use  `facet_wrap(~var, labeller = labeller(var = names_head))`.

Now, I want to modify these headers

[image]

to have a subscript after each "S", i.e. "|S_0| = ...". I have tried different versions and to use `label_parsed()` instead of providing a manual labeller but it didn't work. Can I somehow adjust my manual labeller `names_head` to add the subscript to the "|S|" expressions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
library(ggplot2)

dat <- iris
xxx <- c("S[0]", "S[1]", "S[2]")
names(xxx) <- levels(dat$Species)

ggplot(dat, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) + geom_point() + 
  facet_wrap(~ Species, labeller = labeller(Species = xxx, .default = label_parsed))
```

[image]

The subscript in a R math expression is done with brackets, not with an underscore. See `?plotmath` for the doc.

---

## EDIT

Following the comment:

```
library(ggplot2)

dat <- iris
xxx <- c("S[0]", "S[1]", "S^2")
names(xxx) <- levels(dat$Species)

mylabeller <- function(newlabels){
  function(labels){
    lapply(as.list(labels), function(levels){
      lapply(levels, function(level){
        newlabel <- newlabels[[level]]
        if(grepl("\\[", newlabel) && grepl("\\]", newlabel)){
          parse(text = newlabel)
        }else{
          newlabel
        }
      })
    })
  }
}

ggplot(dat, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) + geom_point() + 
  facet_wrap(~ Species, labeller = mylabeller(xxx))
```

---

## EDIT

I think I didn't understand the question. In fact, the OP got an error when passing something like `|S[0]| = 10` to `label_parsed`. The needed R math expression here is `"group('|',S[0],'|') == 10"`. Again, see `?plotmath` for the doc on R math expressions.

Comment: Yes, I know. I have tried it this way by using label_parsed, but then the remaining labels not including the subscript are not edited properly. Therefore, I have asked a solution without label_parsed but adjusting my own labeller

Comment: @Leo96 Please see my edit. This labeller turns a label into a math expression only if this label has a subscript, otherwise it keeps it as is.

Comment: Thanks for updating it, but although it works with "S[0]", as soon as I use the absolute signs around it and the "=10" it does not work anymore, i.e. "|S[0]| = 10".I need the horizontal lines to denote that this denotes a cardinality (as in my last picture of my initial post but added with a subscript).

Comment: @Leo96 If you want a subscript then you have no other choice than inputting a R math expression. So here you have to do `"group('|',S[0],'|') == 10"`.

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks. Do you want to update your post such that I can accept the answer ?